# Streams: Avoid NullPointerException

Tags: java, java-8

I have to get the first element of an array., but it is possible that the element is empty; If the element is empty I put an empty field (I am trying to generate a pdf)

Here is my code now:

```
public void makePdf(Long id) throws IOException {
    Candidacy ca = candidacyRepository.findOne(id); 
    cos.beginText();

    cos.showText(
       ca.getInterviews().stream().map(Interview::getAgency).map(Agency::getAgencyName).collect( Collectors.toList()).get(0)!=null?ca.getInterviews().stream().map(Interview::getAgency).map(Agency::getAgencyName).collect( Collectors.toList()).get(0):"")); 

    cos.endText();
}
```

So I will wish not to prevent the generation of the pdf.
Thank you very much for your support!

**UPDATE**

Sorry for the lack of precision:
I also sort on the date.

```
public void makePdf(Long id) throws IOException {
        Candidacy ca = candidacyRepository.findOne(id); 
        cos.beginText();

        cos.showText(
           ca.getInterviews().stream().sorted((a,b)-> a.getInterviewDate().compareTo(b.getInterviewDate())).sorted((a,f)->f.getInterviewDate().compareTo(a.getInterviewDate())).sorted((b,f)->b.getInterviewDate().compareTo(f.getInterviewDate())).map(Interview::getAgency).map(Agency::getAgencyName).collect( Collectors.toList()).get(0)!=null?ca.getInterviews().stream().sorted((a,b)-> a.getInterviewDate().compareTo(b.getInterviewDate())).sorted((a,f)->f.getInterviewDate().compareTo(a.getInterviewDate())).sorted((b,f)->b.getInterviewDate().compareTo(f.getInterviewDate())).map(Interview::getAgency).map(Agency::getAgencyName).collect( Collectors.toList()).get(0):"")); 

        cos.endText();
    }
```

I get a NullPointerException:/
Thank you for you help

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Add `.filter(i -> i != null)` just after you stream the collection.

Comment: Just a side note, don’t have a bad feeling yourself, when repeating a 110 characters long expression? Doesn’t come the idea of putting the result into a local variable into your mind?

Answer (score 5):

This code doesn't make sense. You are executing the same `Stream` pipeline twice, and each time you generate an entire `List` when you only need the first element of that `List`.

You can use `findFirst` to get the first element of the `Stream`.

EDIT :

After testing my original answer, it turned out it doesn't work. `findFirst()` throws a `NullPointerException` if the first element is `null`.

You can avoid that by setting the default value before calling `findFirst()` :

```
ca.getInterviews().stream()
                  .map(Interview::getAgency)
                  .map(Agency::getAgencyName)
                  .map(s->s!=null?s:"") // this will replace null with ""
                  .firstFirst()
                  .get();
```

Comment: I would use `.filter(s -> s != null)` or `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` then you will get the first non `null` value.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I didn't think that was the intent - based on the OP's code, the intent was to get the first element and convert it to "" if it's null, not to filter out the `null` values. I might be wrong though.

Comment: I was thinking the use of `""` was a work around but you could be right.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of precision: I must sort on three elements, That's why I have not used "findFirst()".

Comment: @AdamD But you only take the first element of the list after sorting the stream and collecting to a List. `findFirst()` will still work (but all the elements of the Stream will be processed, in order to sort them).

Comment: @Eran In fact, I executed as you have shown me but I still have NullPointerException

Comment: @AdamD Is it possible that `getAgency()` returns null?

Comment: @Eran , yes of course

Comment: @AdamD And if `getAgency()` of the first `Interview` is null, what do you want to return? Perhaps it would be better to just filter out such elements (i.e. `...map(Interview::getAgency).filter(Objects::nonNull).map(Agency::getAgencyName)...`)